# Are we on the same page with [pagination] and [paging]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just logged in a [duplicate suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) to make "pagination" a duplicate of "paging":

[paging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) has 53 questions, [pagination](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination) currently only 4.

But then I felt, the term **"pagination" would be the better fit** for the subject of dividing results into discrete pages, and this just started off on the wrong foot.

I cannot log in the reverse synonym as my score for "paging" is too low.

The current [tag description for paging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/paging/info) is:

> Separating results into equally-sized 'pages' typically for display purposes. Also known as pagination.

[Wikpidia about "pagination"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination):

> Pagination, also known as paging, is the process of dividing a document into discrete pages, either electronic pages or printed pages.

*Also known as paging*, but "paging" is more commonly known to be about memory management on the OS level. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging):

> In computer operating systems, memory paging is a memory management scheme by which a computer stores and retrieves data from secondary storage for use in main memory.

On Stackoverflow, I see 2368 questions tagged ["paging"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paging), but 16672 for ["pagination"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination).

The term "pagination" is used much more commonly than "paging" in the tagged posts.

I suggest to **use "pagination"** and make "paging" a synonym. Would you agree?

Answer (score 5):

Yep I agree with this. Will wait a while to see what other feedback comes in.

I have made [pagination](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination) a synonym of [paging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) for the moment, but that is easily swapped.

---

There were no objections, so I have made [paging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) a synonym of [pagination](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination) and merged the tags.

Answer (score 5):

I would agree that pagination is the correct term. With out additional context, when I hear paging, my first thought goes to memory paging to disk, not a subset of rows being returned to a webpage.